# How to show dates between 2 dates without time Js

Tags: javascript, date, time, date-range

So I have this code that gives me the dates between date A and date B, but it also shows the time which I dont want.

This is my current code that works:

```js
function getDatesInRange(startDate, endDate) {
  const date = new Date(startDate.getTime());
  const dates = [];
  while (date <= endDate) {
    dates.push(new Date(date));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return dates;
}

const d1 = new Date("2022-01-18");
const d2 = new Date("2022-01-24");

console.log(getDatesInRange(d1, d2));
```

I saw online even here that some say to use

```js
return dates.split(" ")[0];
```

But it still returns the time.

How can I return only the date **(year, month, day)** and not time?

Comment: Just change `dates.push(new Date(date))` to `dates.push(new Date(date).toDateString())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString):

```js
function getDatesInRange(startDate, endDate) {
  const date = new Date(startDate.getTime());
  const dates = [];
  while (date <= endDate) {
    dates.push(new Date(date));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return dates;
}

const d1 = new Date('2022-01-18');
const d2 = new Date('2022-01-24');

console.log(getDatesInRange(d1, d2).map(date => date.toDateString()));
```

Which will get the date, map it to find only the "date" (not time) and `console.log` it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the moment library to format the return.
https://momentjs.com/

getDatesInRange(d1, d2).map(date => moment(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))

Comment: Hi, maybe author was looking for a solution in plain JavaScript, without any library